# Array with stopping condition

Tags: c, arrays

The task is: a user types an `char` array and the programm stops when the last two values make a match with the first and second inserted values, then it prints only inserted `int` values.

For example, I type: 1,2,f,5,2,g,s,d,c,3,1,2

And get 1,2,5,3

This what I've got for now

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    char* A;
    int i = 2, N;

    //making an array
    A = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter an array   \n");

    //entering the first value
    scanf_s("%c", &A[0]);
    //second value
    scanf_s("%c", &A[1]);

    //next values
    while (!(A[i - 1] == A[0] && A[i] == A[1]))
    {
        i++;
        A = (char*)realloc(A, (i + 1)*sizeof(char));
        scanf_s("%c", &A[i]);
    } 


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So now it makes a stop only if *the first* value makes a match and prints nothing. I am really confused

Comment: Your `while` loop is invalid because `A[i]` will be out of bounds by one all the time. First `A` is of size 2, but you check index 2 which would be the third entry. If I were you I would simplify things by having a real array of size 2 with the first user input, then read the rest into another variable so that you can compare it properly. With your current loop it's not possible to input `2 2` as first input or anything where the first two matches etc.

Comment: This is remarkably poorly specified. For example, *any* first two values are simultaneously the last two values just as they are entered. Coincidentally, they also match themselves. And if you forbid two entries from signaling the end, how about three times the same value? The last two values once again match the first two, while the second value is used twice. I'd recommend you come up with reasonable rules first.

Comment: and `A[2]` is never set.

Comment: @francis `A[2]` is out of range from `A = (char*)malloc(2 * sizeof(char));`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid dynamically allocating altogether and just focus on the logic of your task. While you can use `scanf` for reading character input, you are better served using a *character-oriented* input function such as `getchar`.

That said, it appears you want to read characters from `stdin`, only storing unique digits in your array, and then if the user enters digits that match your first two elements stored in your array, print the values stored in the array and exit. (If I have any of that wrong, please let me know in a comment)

First off, reading characters with `scanf` can be a bit finicky depending on the values separating the character. However since you are only concerned with storing digits, that makes things a bit easier.

To avoid dealing with `malloc`, just set some reasonable limit to size your array and check your stored elements against. A simple `#define` is all you need. For example:

```
#define MAXE 128
```

Will define a constant `MAXE` (for max elements), to test against as you fill your array. Just keep a count of the elements you add to the array, and if you reach your limit, exit.

You want to keep reading characters until one of two conditions are met: (1) you have added 128 values to your array with no exit condition tripped, or (2) the last two characters entered match the digits store in `a[0]` and `a[1]`. To set up your read you can do something like:

```
   while (n < MAXE && scanf ("%c", &c) == 1) { ...
```

**note:** with `getchar()` you can avoid the non-portable `_s` function issue, among other pitfalls with the `scanf` family of functions. The changes are minimal to use `getchar()` instead of declaring `c` as type `char`, declare `c` as type `int`, and then change your assignment to `c` as follows:

```
   while (n < MAXE && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
```

After reading a character, (regardless of how), you want to test whether it is a digit, if not you are not storing it and it can't be part of your exit condition. So you can simply get the next char if it isn't a digit:

```
        if (c < '0' || '9' < c)
            continue;
```

(**note:** `ctype.h` provides the `isdigit()` function that can be used instead of the manual checks)

You want to store the first two digit regardless, and following those two, you want to store any new digits entered (not already stored), so you need to test the current digit against all digits previously stored to insure it is a unique digit. While you can code the logic several ways, in this case your test loop must test all values stored before making a decision to store the current digit. In this situation, and in situations where you need to break control within nested loop, the lowly `goto` statement is your best friend. Here if the digit is a duplicate, the `goto` simply skips to the `dupes` label passing over the assignment:

```
        if (n > 1)
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (c == a[i])
                    goto dupe;
        a[n++] = c;
        dupe:;
```

The last part of the puzzle is your exit condition. This is a bit tricky (but simply solved) because you know you will not store the preceding (or for Leffler, the *penultimate*) value in the array to test against (it being non-unique to the array). The trick is just to save the character from the last iteration to test against. (maybe in a variable called `last`). Now you can code your exit clause:

```
        if (n > 2 && a[0] == last && a[1] == c)
            break;
```

Putting it all together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXE 128

int main (void) {

    char a[MAXE] = "", c, last = 'a';
    int i, n = 0;

    printf ("Enter an array\n");

    while (n < MAXE && scanf ("%c", &c) == 1) {
        if (c < '0' || '9' < c)
            continue;
        if (n > 1)
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (c == a[i])
                    goto dupe;
        a[n++] = c;
        dupe:;
        if (n > 2 && a[0] == last && a[1] == c)
            break;
        last = c;
    }

    if (n < 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: minimum of 3 values required.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (n == MAXE) {
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: limit of values reached.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Values in array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        putchar (a[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

How you handle the printing and error conditions are up to you. Those included above are just a thought on how you could cover your bases.

**Note:** gcc does not implement the optional `_s` functions, so you can make the change back to `scanf_s` if you need to.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/exitonmatch
Enter an array
1
2
f
5
2
g
s
d
c
3
1
2
Values in array: 1253
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

---

**Accept Any Char as Termination/Store only Unique Digits**

If the logic as you have explained, is to track the first two characters, regardless of whether they are digits and allow any character to serve as the termination check of first two entered sequence, the easiest way to handle that is to simply store the first two characters entered in a separate array (or two variables) and check each sequence of characters entered against them.

Adding this type check takes no more than a slight rearranging of the conditions in the original to allow a few checks on any character entered before considering only digits for storage in your array.

*note:* the `cc` (character count) variable was added to track the number of characters entered and the `first` array was added to hold the first two characters entered.

For example:

```
    char a[MAXE] = "", first[TSTA] = "", last = 'a';
    int c, cc = 0, i, n = 0;

    printf ("Enter an array\n");

    while (n < MAXE && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c < ' ') continue;  /* skip non-print chars */
        if (cc < 2)             /* fill first[0] & [1]  */
            first[cc] = c;      /* check term condition */
        if (++cc > 2 && first[0] == last && first[1] == c)
            break;
        last = c;               /* set last */
        if (c < '0' || '9' < c) /* store only numbers   */
            continue;
        if (n > 1)              /* skip duplicates      */
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                if (c == a[i])
                    goto dupe;
        a[n++] = c;  /* digit and not a dupe - store it */
        dupe:;
    }
```

**note:** `getchar` is used above, but you can substitute `scanf` from the first example if you like.

**Example Use/Output**

Here there first two characters are `a` and `b` which serve as the termination sequence despite not being digits.

```
$ ./bin/exitonmatchgc
Enter an array
a
b
c
4
5
g
h
4
9
3
b
a
b
Values in array: 4593
```

Comment: everything works, but stops array does not work, if you start to write, for example: 1 q, it only works if the first char are numbers

Comment: No problem, I thought you only wanted to store numbers. If you want the first 2 to also be characters, then you will need to save the first 2 values for the termination clause. Hold on and I'll update based on this criteria. To be clear, you are saying track the first two -- even if not numbers and will not be stored in `a`, but still consider those for termination?